# How to range partition a table alphabetically?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, range, partition

I think I may have the syntax wrong, when I query P0 for example, I get school names starting with all letters - its not restricted to letters A-E, which is what I want.

```
   CREATE TABLE "AB"."SCHOOL4" 
   (    "SCHOOL_KEY" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "SCHOOL_IDENTIFIER" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "SCHOOL_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
      PARTITION BY RANGE (SCHOOL_NAME)
       (  PARTITION P0 VALUES LESS THAN ('F'),
          PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('Q'),
          PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
           )
      TABLESPACE AB_ST2;
```

My Question:
   How would I accomplish partitioning this table so that the values were partition alphabetically A-E, F-R, Q-Z?

My query:

```
SELECT SCHOOL_NAME FROM SCHOOL4, DBA_SEGMENTS
Where PARTITION_NAME = 'P0' and owner = 'AB' ;
```

I changed the query to what Xion suggested below and it brought up the intended values.

Comment: Can you write how you query it ?

Comment: SELECT SCHOOL_NAME FROM SCHOOL4, DBA_SEGMENTS
Where PARTITION_NAME = 'P0' and owner = 'AB' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try querying it like this

```
Select * from SCHOOL4 partition (p0)
```

Comment: This brought up what I had intended. Thanks.